# Can I program the touchscreen?

Tags: touchscreen, ros

I want to read the x,y coordinates whenever a user touches or uses a stylus to touch a screen in Ubuntu 16.04. This is because I am using ROS on my Ubuntu and I want to control the ROS nodes from another device which has a touchscreen in it.

Before this, I was trying to use rosjava in Android, but after finding that Ubuntu 16.04 supports the touchscreen, I also felt that there should be some method to access the x,y or pressure datas of the positions where user touches in the screen. However, I didn't find any example code or methods in internet.

Can someone show me guidelines for programming the touchscreen?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28841139/how-to-get-coordinates-of-touchscreen-rawdata-using-linux

Comment: well i meant, touchscreen of the computer itself where ubuntu is running not outer touchscreen which is connected using usb cable. cas i need to run ubuntu+ros on that system too.

Comment: You can get coordinates of any touchscreen using `evtest` or other tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can briefly explain how to get the co-ordinates.

First run the `xinput` command to detect your touchscreen id.

Then run `xinput list-props <id>` to get the event number. Let it be e.g. `/dev/input/event5`.

Run

```
sudo evtest /dev/input/event5
```

and you will get all the touchpad events: touches, coordinates, etc.

Now you can parse this output and use it for some programming.